# paintComponent deletes the previously painted components

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I am writing a simple painting program.
I have created a `JPanel`, and have over written "public void `paintComponent(Graphics g)`", I have also created the appropriate `Listeners`. The problem is that everytime I draw a new shape, my previous one vanishes, Does anyone know how I can keep the previous shapes in their place? I can take the `super.paintComponent(g)` away, but then the `Jpanel's` `layout` will be distorted. 
Any suggestion is highly appreciated. :)
this is my paintComponent method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);


    int width = xend-xstart;
    int height = yend - ystart;
    if(width<0)
        width *= -1;
    if(height <0)
        height *= -1;
    if(color!= null && shape !=null){
    if(fill.isSelected())
    {
        g.setColor(color);
        if(shape.equals("Rectangle"))
            g.fillRect(xstart, ystart, width, height);
        if(shape.equals("Square"))
            g.fillRect(xstart, ystart, width, width);
        if(shape.equals("Circle"))
            g.fillOval(xstart,ystart,width ,width);

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson Thank you, but wouldnt this affect the efficiency as I draw more and more shapes? because then the paintComponent has to draw many shapes everytime I call repaint();

Comment: Thanks, you are right :) also I need to write an undo function and a List will be useful in that case too :) thanks for the help

Answer (score 4):

To draw multiple "Rectangle", "Square" or "Circle" objects it will be necessary to add them to a collection (e.g. [`ArrayList‌`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)​) and each call to `paintComponent(Graphics)`, iterate the collection and draw each one.

Either that or draw the shapes in a [`BufferedImage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) and draw the image instead.

> ..wouldnt this affect the efficiency as I draw more and more shapes? because then the paintComponent has to draw many shapes everytime I call repaint();

There are 3 answers that I can give to that.  Here they are:

1. Yes it would.
2. But no, there would have to be *thousands* before causing visible slow-down.
3. In the event that performance is a problem. Use the `BufferedImage`. That way only one more shape is drawn to the image for each newly added shape, no matter how many ***..millions*** have previously been rendered to it.

> ..also I need to write an undo function and a List will be useful in that case too

It does sound like the list is the way to go for this use-case.

Comment: answer is better than comment +1

Comment: @mKorbel I do enjoy the luxury of using in my answers:- paragraphs, quoted material, ordered lists, more than 600 chars.  At least once they have evolved beyond comments.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Andrew Thompson's answer is the "typical" way to do what you want.  However, if you want to plunge deeper into the depths of Swing...

One of the things that super.paintComponent() does (eventually) is get to `JComponent.paintComponent()`, which calls `ComponentUI.update()`.  The Javadocs say (italics added by me):

"By default this method will fill the specified component with its background color (*if its opaque property is true*) and then immediately call paint."

So, try calling `setOpaque(false)`.  However, that often leads to other issues, such as when you really *do* want to erase what was drawn before.